# Позиционирование в файле c++

Tags: c++, файлы, функции, позиционирование

Создать функцию, которая с использованием функций позиционирования в потоке изменяет содержимое файла "array.dat", переданного ей в качестве параметра. А именно, функция переставляет все нулевые элементы в начало файла. (В этот файл мы записали массив, рандомных интовых элементов).

Answer (score 1):

Проходим по файлу с конца, удаляем все нулевые элементы. Т. е. один указатель для чтения сдвигается постоянно, а второй для записи сдвигается только если там не 0. Когда первый дойдёт до начала файла, записываем от начала до второго нолики.

Само позиционирование для типа `FILE*` осуществляется функцией `fseek`.
Для `fstream` надо использовать методы `seekg` и `seekp`.

А вообще, это для массива было бы хорошо, а на файле из-за позиционирования может медленно работать - возможно, надо оптимизировать, но в качестве первого приближения пойдёт.

Comment: Как же это вы умудрились. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ой.. Не знаю, отвлёкся xD

Comment: У меня проблема в том, что я не понимаю как из файла считывать поэлементно. получается только посимвольно. Поэтому когда я встречаю 0 в двузначном числе (например 20) появляются дополнительные проблемы. То есть мне в начало файла нужно поместить нулевые элементы, а не символы 0.

Comment: @RioCrash, `FILE *input=...; int x; fread((void*)&x, sizeof(x), 1, input);`.

Comment: Я скорее всего очень сильно туплю, но у меня действительно не получается. Если кто-нибудь сможет написать код для решения этой задачи, буду очень  очень благодарен.

Comment: Скорее всего делать это в файле просто не разумно, из за производительности и накладных расходов на количество телодвижений. За 'мап'те файл как буфер.

Comment: Наверное, все же, указатель чтения (тот, что идет от начала файла к концу) должен сдвигаться, когда мы ищем не нулевой элемент, который будем записывать по второму указателю, который двигается от конца к началу в поисках нулей. Завершаем (и далее обнуляем голову), когда указатели *встретились*. Что же касается производительности, то поскольку файловые операции буферизуются в userspace, то ничего страшного не произойдет.

Comment: @avp, почему с начала? Это как-то бессмысленно. Я про вот такой алгоритм: `var a, l, r;
var a = Array(100).fill().map(x => Math.random()*4 | 0);
console.log(a.join(""));
for (l=r=a.length-1; ~l; --l) if (a[l]) a[r--]=a[l];
for (; ~r; --r) a[r]=0;
console.log(a.join(""));` https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1XUN.png. А вот буферизация у меня вызывает вопросы. Во-первы, скорее всего она вперёд, а не назад, а тут сдвиг назад по 4 байта на каждом шаге. Во-вторых, есть подозрение, что seek автоматически делает flush?

Comment: @RioCrash, вон, переписывай с массива на js на файлы на плюсах.

Comment: @Qwertiy, переставить нулевые в начало это значит заполнить все места, которые они занимали в конце, ненулевыми из начала (никто ведь не говорил о сохранении частичной упорядоченности). Не надо переписывать все ненулевые назад. Лишнее это. Даже если работать не с файлом, а с массивом в памяти.

Comment: @avp, чего?? Нулевые в начало - значит нулевые в начало. А из остального выкинуть эти переставленные нулевые и поместить за ними. `a.filter(x => !x).concat(a.filter(x => x))`. А что ты предлагаешь, я вообще не понял.

Comment: Не надо нулевые постоянно писать в начало (обменивать). Потом начало обнулим. Ладно, время поздее и либо я ошибаюсь, либо вы завтра сообразите.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91389/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-avp).

Comment: Завтра, уже только завтра, а сейчас спать.